# Weekly count - occurrence of unique column values, and display max count

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am attempting to create a weekly count of unique column value occurrences, and find the top weekly count for each occurrence over the given time-period. An example of the initial DataFrame can be seen below.

```html
date            company

2014-12-01  bank of america corp
2014-12-01  bank of america corp
2014-12-01  jpmorgan chase & co
2014-12-01  jpmorgan chase & co
2014-12-01  morgan stanley
2014-12-01      morgan stanley
2014-12-01  intel corp
2014-12-01  goldman sachs group inc
2014-12-01  bank of america corp
2014-12-01  jpmorgan chase & co
2014-12-02      berkshire hathaway inc
2014-12-02  berkshire hathaway inc
2014-12-02      berkshire hathaway inc
2014-12-02  berkshire hathaway inc
2014-12-02  bank of america corp
2014-12-02  bank of america corp
2014-12-02  jpmorgan chase & co
2014-12-02      jpmorgan chase & co
2014-12-02      morgan stanley
2014-12-03  morgan stanley
2014-12-03  jpmorgan chase & co
2014-12-03  bank of america corp
2014-12-03  morgan stanley
2014-12-03  goldman sachs group inc
2014-12-03      bank of america corp
2014-12-03  jpmorgan chase & co
2014-12-03  goldman sachs group inc
.....           ...........
```

I am attempting to create a company count with the DataFrame grouped by week, with the top week for each company occurrence shown. Each company should have one row containing the week with the most mentions. An example of the intended DataFrame can be seen below:

```html
date            company                   top_week_count

2014-12-07  bank of america corp      22
2014-12-07  jpmorgan chase & co       12
2014-12-14  morgan stanley            15
2014-12-14  goldman sachs group inc   29
2014-12-21  berkshire hathaway inc    35
.....           ....                      ..
```

The above DataFrames are only a brief snippet of the entire DF's, which span over a number of years.

Any assistance anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date'),'company'])['company']\
.agg(['count']).reset_index().sort_values('count',ascending=False)
        date                      company  count
0 2014-12-07         bank of america corp      7
5 2014-12-07          jpmorgan chase & co      7
6 2014-12-07               morgan stanley      5
1 2014-12-07       berkshire hathaway inc      4
2 2014-12-07      goldman sachs group inc      2
3 2014-12-07  goldman sachs group inc/the      1
4 2014-12-07                   intel corp      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
df['weekend'] = df['date'] + Week(weekday=4)
df.groupby(['weekend', 'company']).size().reset_index(name = 'top_week_count')

    weekend     company                top_week_count
0   2014-12-05  bank of america corp    7
1   2014-12-05  berkshire hathaway inc  4
2   2014-12-05  goldman sachs group inc 3
3   2014-12-05  intel corp              1
4   2014-12-05  jpmorgan chase & co     7
5   2014-12-05  morgan stanley          5
```